# Keep text between [] Java

Tags: java, search

i have several strings (they are like 600 thousand++) that are like this:

[59395820]: English for Academic Study: Vocabulary 2012 edition - Study Book, Colin Campbell

[2651]: Η ΑΝΑΓΕΝΝΗΣΗ ΤΟΥ ΝΟΗΜΑΤΟΣ, ΧΡΥΣΗ ΚΑΡΑΤΣΙΝΙΔΟΥ

[17067]: Discours Action Interaction, Κέλλα Βασιλική

and i only want to keep the values between []. For example on the first string i want to keep 59395820 etc..

Is there any way to keep it while not using regex,jsoup  etc? 
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String newString =s.substring(s.indexOf('[')+1,s.indexOf(']'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split()`, in your case:

```java
yourString.split("\\[")[1].split("\\]")[0];
```

We split on the "[", which we have to escape with "\" to avoid regex. We take everything after this character by getting the 2nd element of the split array. Then we split again on the "]", and take everything before that by getting the 1st element of the second split array.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String test = "[59395820]: English for Academic Study: Vocabulary 2012 edition - Study Book, Colin Campbell";

  String result = test.split("\\[")[1].split("\\]")[0];

  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, it actually works but i am curious if a method that someone replied above is faster

String newString =s.substring(s.indexOf('[')+1,s.indexOf(']'));
It was this solution instead of 
String result = test.split("\\[")[1].split("\\]")[0];
I guess its the same ?

Comment: @AggelosKypraios I'm not sure about speed but you could easily test that for yourself. I will say that my solution is certainly taking up extra memory (space complexity) compared to the substring solution.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can get the indices of the brackets:

```
int start=str.indexOf('[');
int end=str.indexOf(']',start);
```

After that, you can just use `substring` to get the content between the brackets:

```
String inBrackets=str.substring(start+1,end);
```

Ifyou want to do this with every element, it would be something like:

```
int start,end=0;
while((start=str.indexOf('[',end))!=-1&&(end=str.indexOf('[',start))!=-1){
    System.out.println(str.substring(start+1,end));
}
```